# How to create source data file for training and testing file in libsvm?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, svm, libsvm

I want to use a dataset to train a model. The dataset has three different types of physiological data. type 1, type 2 and type 3. The format of the libSVM is as below:
label index1:value1 index2:value2....

Now, I have taken label as 1 for type 1, 2 for type 2 and 3 for type 3. Where as all the values are save as 1:(value). So, my training and testing file is as below.

1 1:value \n
1 1:value \n
1 1:value \n
1 1:value \n
1 1:value \n
.
.
.
1 1:value \n
2 1:value \n
2 1:value \n
2 1:value \n
2 1:value \n
2 1:value \n
.
.
.
2 1:value \n
3 1:value \n 
3 1:value \n
3 1:value \n
3 1:value \n
.
.
.
3 1:value \n

So, I am traing the svm with this kind of source file and testing with similar kind of source file. I want to make sure if I am using the SVM data format correctly. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The vector dataset format for [LIBSVM](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) is defined as

```
label feature_id1:feature_value1 feature_id2:feature_value2 ...
```

Thus, every feature (or value) needs is own unique identifier.

**Example:**

Imagine you have three different class labels `1,2,3` and a feature set consisting of `a(id=1),b(id=2),c=(id=3)`, which was obtained via feature selection mechanism.

So let's say, that we have three datapoints `d1,d2,d3`, we want to describe in our dataset, it would be for example:

```
2 1:0.5325 3:0.523

3 2:0.7853 3:0.6326

1 1:0.53265 2:0.5422
```

Meaning:

- `d1` contains feature `a(id=1)` and `c(id=3)`
- `d2` contains feature `b(id=2)` and `c(id=3)`
- `d3` contains feature `a(id=1)` and `b(id=2)`

Note, that it is not necessary to provide `feature_id1:feature_value1` for features, which are not contained in the given datapoint.