# LIBSVM with large data samples

Tags: svm, libsvm

I am currently looking to use [libsvm](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) (or an alternate if it is suggested; [opencv](https://opencv.org) also looks like a viable option) in order to train an SVM. My training data sets are rather large; around 50 binary 128MB files. It appears to use libsvm I must convert the data to a proper format; however I was wondering if it is possible to do training on the raw binary data itself? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's your "raw binary data" look like? would you post the first few features of the first few instances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you **cannot** use your raw binary (image) data for training nor for testing.

In order to use `libsvm` you have to convert your binary data files into this format.

See this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39360296/how-to-create-source-data-file-for-training-and-testing-file-in-libsvm/39496733#39496733) for the details of the `libsvm` data-format.